# Nginx, Docker and Nx Monorepo with one port - 502 Gateway

Tags: docker, nginx, nuxt.js, monorepo, nomachine-nx

i have problem with setup my nginx. I was able to start all "apps/" modules inside docker.
But reverse proxy still doesn't work as expected.

Story:
**Nx directories:**

```
/ apps
  / test-1 (Nuxt)
  / test-2 (Nuxt)
  / test-3 (Nuxt)
```

**docke-compose.yml:**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: local_nginx
    volumes:
       - ./nginx/reverse_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - my_net
  event-module:
    extends:
      file: default.service.yml
      service: start_module
    command: npm run test-1-module-local
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    container_name: local-test-1-module
    networks:
      - my_net
    depends_on:
      - nginx
  portal-module:
    extends:
      file: default.service.yml
      service: start_module
    command: npm run test-2-module-local
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    container_name: local-test-2-module
    networks:
      - my_net
    depends_on:
      - nginx
  user-module:
    extends:
      file: default.service.yml
      service: start_module
    ports:
      - 3003:3003
    container_name: local-test-3-module
    command: npm run test-3-module-local
    networks:
      - my_net
    depends_on:
      - nginx

volumes:
  mono-node-modules: null
networks:
  my_net:
    driver: "bridge"
```

**default.service.yml:**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  start_module:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/nuxt-app
      - mono-node-modules:/nuxt-app/node_modules
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:16.20.1

RUN mkdir -p /nuxt-app
WORKDIR /nuxt-app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run", "test-1-module-local"]
```

**reverse_proxy.conf:**

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    upstream local-test-1-module {
        server 0.0.0.0:3001;
    }
    upstream local-test-2-module {
        server 0.0.0.0:3002;
    }
    upstream local-test-3-module {
        server 0.0.0.0:3003;
    }
    server {
        listen 8080;
        location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://local-test-1-module;
        }
        location /test-2/ {
            proxy_pass http://local-test-2-module;
        }
        location /test-3/ {
            proxy_pass http://local-test-3-module;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to run every module on the same url like `http://localhost:8080/` with module name after base url example:

- `http://localhost:8080/test-1` for test-1
- `http://localhost:8080/test-2` for test-2
- `http://localhost:8080/test-3` for test-3

At the moment all of dem starts at:

- `http://localhost:3001`
- `http://localhost:3002`
- `http://localhost:3003`

Is there any chance to make it? Thank you for you time and help in advice.